# How to iterate an object to print this type of UI in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I have this object. Now I want to iterate this using *ngFor to get the UI (image link is giving below). I am facing issue in making different section.

Here is my Object -

```
[
{
    "number": 1,
    "section": "Section 1"
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "section": "Section 1",
},
{
    "number": 3,
    "section": "Section 1"
},
{
    "number": 1,
    
    "section": "Section 2"
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "section": "Section 2"
},
{
    "number": 1,
    "section": "Section 3"
},
{
    "number": 1,
    "section": "Section 4"
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "section": "Section 4"
}
]
```

[This is the screen which I want to develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSslX.png)

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's array.reduce() to restructure your array in the format you want.

```js
var data = [
{
    "number": 1,
    "section": "Section 1"
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "section": "Section 1",
},
{
    "number": 3,
    "section": "Section 1"
},
{
    "number": 1,
    
    "section": "Section 2"
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "section": "Section 2"
},
{
    "number": 1,
    "section": "Section 3"
},
{
    "number": 1,
    "section": "Section 4"
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "section": "Section 4"
}
]

let group = data.reduce((x, y) => {
 x[y.section] = [...x[y.section] || [], y];
 return x;
}, {});

console.log(group)
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)